# Can't open pdf with GeckoFX

Tags: c#, geckofx

I am not able to upload pdf to my browser ... on the output I am getting the following messages:

```
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: plugin.scan.Acrobat
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: plugin.scan.Quicktime
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: plugin.scan.Acrobat
Gecko.Xpcom.DirectoryServiceProvider.GetFile: not implemented: plugin.scan.Quicktime
```

How can I solve this?

C# GECKO 45.0.34.0

Comment: You can use https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js. If you need acrobat, you can just do that in c#. See https://github.com/BloomBooks/BloomDesktop/tree/master/src/BloomExe/Publish/PDF for example.

Comment: I solved the problem by installing the Foxit Pdf Reader is marking the option to open the pdf in the browser!